# Surface Sample Applications doesn't start

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, touch, pixelsense

I'm trying to develop a multitouch application using Surface 2.0 SDK, so I've installed its sample applications.
I opened the solution in Visual Studio 2010 ultimate, but I noticed that the debug starts, but it seems like to be in a without exit loop or waiting for something.
Example:
I start the project named ControlsBox, I wait for one/two minutes, and everytime that I press pause the application is in:

```
System.Windows.Input.PenThreadWorker.GetTabletInfoHelper
```

I'm developing on a non-touch pc with Windows 7 Pro.
Looking in processes I noticed that if I stop wisptis.exe the application finally run.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. This happens both with the sample applications and my own projects. The code runs fine on the Pixelsense.

Comment: Also, when the input simulator (wisptis.exe?) is not running, it works as well. When starting the input simulator after launching the application, the window does not register tags and other events from the input simulator.

This setup worked half a year ago, I'm thinking a Windows 7 update might have caused a problem.

Comment: @MintL exactly the wisptis.exe process is my problem, if I kill it 3/4 seconds after debug starts, my application works.. (But it is not a good workauround..)

Comment: The workaround worked on my computer as well. I have no idea what causes this but thanks anyway. Please let me know if you find anything and I'll do the same.